# How can I hide the connect_widget_user_action class in like facebook button?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, hide

I have a facebook like button in my web site in the home page.
The code for it is:

```
 <div><iframe id="ifFacebook" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.MYSITE.com%2F&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"  style="margin-top:0px; overflow:hidden; width:250px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></div>
```

If I am not logged in Facebook, then I have the option to click the Like button. I click the button, I get the facebook pop up window for login, I login and then for some seconds I can see a text regarding my actions, which is fade out and replaced by "You and x others like this. Add Comment"

I want to always hide the text about my actions, and don't make it visible even for seconds. I see that is is in the connect_widget_user_action class in facebook iframe.

Does anyone know how can I disable this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Content loaded in an iframe is not accessible from the parent document for security reasons. Depending on the browser, it might allow access if both documents are served from the same domain, but that's not the case here.

You could try using an older social plugin like the fan box which allowed to specify a CSS file and trim that down. I don't know if those still work. They might stop doing so at any time.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Ok I will try something different then. I will make my div a bit bigger so as to see it in a better way at least. Thanks again.